# Facing issue while installing tensorflow.js via npm

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, npm

Used the following cmd (as given in the tensorflow docs) : npm install -g @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Tried to figure out the issue, but unable to find a solution. Kindly help in resolving this. (Thanks in Advance)

The image below shows the error I am getting.

[image: installation error]

Comment: What is you node version??

Comment: i am using node v8.10.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to either install node-gyp (https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation) or ensure that the right version of python is accessible to it.

If you've already got node-gyp and python 2.7 installed, run `npm config set python python2.7` to configure npm to use it.

Comment: This is what I am getting now:

Error: node-gyp rebuild failed with: Error: Command failed: node-gyp rebuild
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)